# How to apply placeholder in select dropdown along with [ngmodel] in angular 6?

Tags: html, angular, select, ngmodel

whenever I use [(ngModel)] first value becomes empty. but when I remove [(ngModel)] it is working fine.

```
 <select class="custom-select" id="campaignDropdown" [(ngModel)]="campaignInfo" placeholder="Select Campaign" (change)="hitApiFunction(campaignInfo)">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select Campaign</option>
              <option *ngFor="let campData of campaigns" [ngValue]="campData"> 
                  {{campData.campaign_name}}
              </option>
            </select>
```

Comment: How have you declared your campaingnInfo in .ts?

Comment: As per your html try to assign campaignInfo with empty string like i.e. campaignInfo:any = ' '; inside your component.ts and it will work for you.

Comment: I tried both the ways by assigning campaignInfo by ' ' and also by campaignInfo : any = "Select Campaign"; but still it is same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thank you everyone who tried to give an answer... its working fine now, correct ans is....

```
<select class="custom-select" id="campaignDropdown" [(ngModel)]="campaignInfo" (change)="hitApiFunction(campaignInfo)">
            <option [value]="0" disabled selected>Select Campaign</option>
              <option *ngFor="let campData of campaigns" [ngValue]="campData"> 
                  {{campData.campaign_name}}
              </option>
            </select>
```

and in ts file
      campaignInfo=0;

Answer (score 3):

By @Krishna Rathore

You can use [value]="" selected hidden

I have create a demo on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/give-placeholder-to-select-in-angular-6?file=src/app/app.component.html)

```
<form role="form" class="form form-horizontal" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #form="ngForm" ngNativeValidate>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-6 col-md-12">
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <label for="customSelect">Categories:</label>
                <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="Category" [(ngModel)]="Category" name="Category" required placeholder="d.ff">
                    <option hidden [value]=""  selected>Select one category </option>
                    <option *ngFor="let item of myBusinessList" [value]="item.id">{{item.name}}</option>
                </select>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-raised btn-danger">Save</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to assign the campaignInfo variable with the placeholder text in your component.ts file.

e.g

```
export class CampaignComponent{
 campaignInfo : any = "";
}
```

the reason behind such behavior of the placeholder being empty is you are adding ngModel in your dropdown and it is not assign with any text yet.
It will work for you because you have **option tag value attribute as = ' ' for option Select Campaign** thats why assign empty string for campaignInfo variable.